# In Github, creating a branch containing only a particular directory

Tags: git, github

I have a project, that is basically making a Total Conversion from an existing game, which resides in GitHub. So I have this original game in a Branch of my repo (let's call it "OriginalGame"), that's linked to the original game's repo and that I keep in synch with it. It's made of C code in /src and data in /dat.

Most of my TC is replacing /dat content with entirely different content. basically, replacing the original game universe with my own. But I sometimes need to make modifications to the C code in /src. These modifications will or not be proposed to be pulled back into the original game.

So here's my problem : I would want to have a branch containing ONLY /src and in synch with the /src in my "BranchOriginalGame" branch (let's call it "OriginalGameCSource"). From this branch, I would derive a branch being "MyCCode" including my own modifications, and that I keep in synch with the "OriginalGameCSource". And I would finally inject that branch, along with my own /dat folder, into my final TC branch, being for instance "MyFinalTC".

The issue for me is, I'm new to Git and GitHub, and I just can't figure how to create the "OriginalGameCSource" by getting only the /src folder from "OriginalGame".

I've already looked into the internet and found some related ideas, but none that seems to solve my issue.

The closest was about "git subtree split" command, but it didn't preserve the directory /src, it dropped all the contents of /src on / instead, which was not the behavior expected. I used the following command :

```
git subtree split --prefix=src --annotate="(split 2015/05/23) " -b NAEV-vanilla-C-Code
```

Comment: This sounds like a possible use case for [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read it in details, but as I'm new to Git, it can take time for me to absorb all this information ^-^